# Simplify expression by introducing user defined functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a very long expression which can be reduced down quite a lot if I define the following functions

```
F[x_] := Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erfc[x]
G[x_] := Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erf[x]
```

where the arguments $x$ that will appear are different (let's say $x1$, $x2$, $x3$...). The result is not a polynomial so I can't get `Collect` to work. I know other people have asked about this but I tried what was suggested in the posts and I couldn't get it to work.

I thought that defining a rule like

```
Erfc[x] -> F[x]/(Sqrt[π] x Exp[x])
Erf[x]  -> G[x]/(Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2])
```

could help, but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Never use capital letters for user-defined functions because that is a convention for internal *Mathematica* functions and can lead to naming conflicts.

Comment: The only thing you have to change is to add a `Blank` like `Erf[x_] -> G[x]/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] x Exp[x^2])`, so e.g. `a^2/Erf[a] /. Erf[x_] -> G[x]/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] x Exp[x^2])` will give `(a^3 E^a^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])/G[a]`.

Answer (score 2):

Once you define functions then they will be evaluated unless you stop their evaluation.

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erfc[x]
g[x_] := Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erf[x]

rules1 = {
   Erfc[x_] :> Inactive[f][x]/(Sqrt[π ] x Exp[x^2]),
   Erf[x_] :> Inactive[g][x]/(Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2])};

f[x] + g[x]

(*  E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erf[x] + 
   E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erfc[x]  *)

% /. rules1

(*  Inactive[f][x] + Inactive[g][x]  *)

% // Activate

(*  E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erf[x] + 
   E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erfc[x]  *)
```

Or use rules for the functions as well

```
Clear[f, g]

rules2 = {
   f[x_] :> Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erfc[x],
   g[x_] :> Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erf[x]};

rules2r = {
   Erfc[x_] :> f[x]/(Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2]),
   Erf[x_] :> g[x]/(Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2])};

Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erfc[x] +
  Sqrt[π] x Exp[x^2] Erf[x] /. 
   rules2r

(*  f[x] + g[x]  *)

% /. rules2

(*  E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erf[x] + 
   E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*x*Erfc[x]  *)
```